# How to customize startup URL when running a Spring MVC web application in STS?

Tags: url, spring-mvc, startup, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm following a [nice tutorial from journaldev.com on Spring MVC](http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite) and succeeded to get the sample application run from [springsource's STS IDE](http://spring.io/tools/sts).

Though when started, the initial URL opened is

`http://localhost:8080/springmvc/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`

which need to be corrected as below as I want to run the default Home controller.

`http://localhost:8080/springmvc/`

How can I change that startup URL when run?

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the code and running the web for a while I figure out the chosen link that Eclipse picks up when starting the web application is **the active/opened file** we are in.

So for the URL `http://localhost:8080/springmvc/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`, I should be opening home.jsp in the editor; and the other link `http://localhost:8080/springmvc/` is when I open nothing ^^